# How to wrire a text file in to specific folder using xpage

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, xpages-ssjs, ssjs

How to create a text file in project folder and i need to send this file as email attachment. Then i need to delete this file.

```
var textBuffer="BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\nVERSION:2.0\r\n...END:VEVENT\r\nEND:VCALENDAR";

file = new java.io.File("c:\\Notes\\sample.ics");

//Create the file
if (file.createNewFile()){

print("File is created!");

}
else{

print("File already exists.");

}

//Write Content
writer = new java.io.FileOutputStream(file);

writer.write(textBuffer.getBytes());

writer.close();

var db:Database  = session.getDatabase("server name", "database name", false);

var doc:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();

doc.appendItemValue("Form", "Memo");

var nMime:NotesMIMEEntity = doc.createMIMEEntity();

var mimeHeader:NotesMIMEHeader;

mimeHeader = nMime.createHeader("To");

mimeHeader.setHeaderVal("email id");

mimeHeader = nMime.createHeader("Subject");

mimeHeader.addValText("Test Email", "UTF-8"); 

var stream:NotesStream = session.createStream();

var pathname:string = "c:\\Notes\\sample.ics";

if (stream.open(pathname, "binary")) {

    nMime.getContentAsBytes(stream);

    stream.close();

    }

nMime.setContentFromBytes(stream, "text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"",NotesMIMEEntity.ENC_NONE);

doc.send();

session.setConvertMIME(true);
```

After this code is excuted i am getting a mail but there is no attachment. Please help me to find what went wrong in this code.

Comment: What have you tried so far? and where did you get stuck? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am able to create the file using response.getOutputStream().write(textBuffer.getBytes()); method but i need to write this file in to a specific folder in my project

Comment: I just need to create a file in my project path folder using ssjs. I am new to SSJS.

Comment: What is "project folder"? Is it accessible from Domino? And why you want to create it there, then delete it?

Comment: It is always problematic if you just copy n paste code from somewhere else without knowing what it does: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35868865/xpages-to-create-txt-file-via-ssjs#35869888

Comment: @SvenHasselbach this is first time i am seeing SSJS and lotus note. Thats why i am not sure how this thing works.

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth For eaxmple i need to create this text file in the webcontent folder of the lotus note application.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 potential answers to your question:

a) with “project folder” you refer to a folder on your local machine (the one running the browser): for security no Webserver can specify the download location. It is a browser setting. That’s for security. It would be too easy to damage a user’s workstation. 
The only way is when you control the browser - which might work for an integration user, but not a user base.

b) “Project folder” is a location on the server (the machine running Domino). There you instantiate a FileOutputStream (a Java Object) and do the same. SSJS can use Java classes.

If you share why you need this, a better solution can be proposed.

Comment: The exact need is to write some content as text file and sent this text file as attachment via mail. Can we store the text file in a document?

Comment: That’s your perception of the requirement. The real one is: create something that gets emailed and received as email with an attachment

Answer (score 0):

You need a complete different approach:
- check the Mime classes in Notes
- create a multipart mime document 
- write your text data into a mime part flagged as attachment

No creation of a file required. See also this answer:
[When generating HTML email using MIME, can attachments be displayed in the Lotus Notes email body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21209016/when-generating-html-email-using-mime-can-attachments-be-displayed-in-the-lotus)

If you insist of creating a physical file: you need to store it on the server `FileOutputStream` style, since the server side attach function doesn’t have access to your local file system